# Widget - Unable to Instantiate Receiver

Tags: android, widget, nullpointerexception

I know similar questions have been asked but none have been helpful to me.  If I were pointed to a link that has a solution I would be more than pleased.  Anyway, I am getting an error every time I install a widget I am developing on my Android Emulator.

The error states
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(866): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver   com.ifractal.firstwidget.FirstWidget: java.lang.NullPointerException

Here is the relevant code

```
AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.ifractal.firstwidget"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <receiver android:name=".FirstWidget" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIGET_ENABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/provider"
        />
    </receiver>
</application>
```

and here is my project layout in eclipse (to show that files are there)
[image]

I have tried recreating the project with a different name, cleaning/building, and a few other things but nothing has worked. I appreciate any help that you can give me and am willing to provide additional info if needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manifest looks fine to me. You get a NPE in FirstWidget, so you need to look into that class. Check the stack trace and see where exactly the exception is thrown. Could it be the constructor?

Comment: well, I got it working.  The issue was in my java file.  I had set a way to update the intent in the onEnabled method which I guess caused the crash.  Didn't think the error was in the java file, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check that your app widget class is not abstract.
Below is a typical app widget class declaration:

```
public class AppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider{
    // ...
}
```